# If $S \subset A$ and $S \neq A$, then is $\text{cl}(S) \subset A$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Synopsis**

I was wondering if it were a true statement that the closure of a set $A$ is the smallest set containing $A$ that is not equal to $A$. In other words, if there exists a set $S$ such that $A \subset S$ but $A \neq S$, then is it true that $\text{cl}(A) \subseteq S$, ***regardless of if $S$ is open or closed***? Can I prove it? Can you give hints if I can? If this statement is false, then please give a counterexample.

*I know that the closure of a set is the smallest closed set, but for an exercise I'm working on, I don't know if the set containing $S$ is open or closed.*

Comment: $A=(0,1),S=(0,0.5)$

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether:

- You are looking at $A$ and $S$ as subsets of another, bigger, ambient topological space $T$, or
- You are looking at the topological space $S$ with its own topology (which it may have inherited from some bigger space $T$ - or not).

In the first case, *your statement is invalid*. Take $A$ to not be closed in $T$ (say $A=B(0,1)$ in $T=\mathbb R^2$ - the open ball) and $S=A$. Then the closed ball $\text{cl}(A)=B[0,1]\not\subseteq S$.

In the second case, *your statement is valid*. Namely, $\text{cl}(A)$ is the *intersection of all closed sets that contain $A$*. Thus, as one of those sets is $S$ itself ($S$ is, in its own topology, both open and closed!), it follows that $\text{cl}(A)\subseteq S$.

The reason the statement is invalid in the first case but valid in the second is that the "closure operator" $\text{cl}$ is in one case taken in $T$ and in the second in $S$ - and it is not the same operator, i.e. closure on $S$ is not a restriction of closure in $T$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is a question in my first year of analysis, so I don't know much about topological spaces yet except for the basic structure of $\mathbb{R}$, but I'll certainly look into this. It's very interesting how the space dictates what answer is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With so little information about sets A, B and the space in which those sets exist, it is very easy to come up with an example when the second inclusion does not hold. Take some space X with trivial topology (that is, only the whole space and the empty set are open) and a least 3 elements a, b, c. Then set A = {a}, S = {a, b}. A $\subset$ S, but cl(A)=X $\nsubseteq$ S.